# google map autocomplete address click

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I've got a Google map and one of their auto complete text boxes, where the user starts typing, addresses are shown in a drop down list, and then the map zooms to the one that's ultimately selected. I'm very happy with what I've got so far; problem is, the user has to click on an address from the list, in order for it to work.

What I would like is also this option: when a user clicks 'ENTER' on the keyboard, even if they have not fully filled in the auto_complete box, the first address in the list is automatically selected, and the map zooms to that.

I was playing around with

```
$(autocomplete).trigger("click");
```

but I couldn't fix it. So, if you could give me a hand, I'd be grateful...The code I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize_google_maps() {



    var midOfIreland = new google.maps.LatLng(53.252069, -7.860718);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: midOfIreland,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
      streetViewControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var input = document.getElementById('address_autocomplete');
    var options = {
      types: ['geocode']
    };

   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    // $(autocomplete).trigger("click");

    var contentstring = $('#info_window').html();


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentstring, width:1, height:1});
// for the 'x', to close the infoWindow, we give it the same behaviour as the 'No' link, in the infoWindow
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {   
  $(".map-no-link").trigger("click");
});  


   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });



    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(11);
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      $('#user_lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
      $('#user_lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      $('#changed').val('1');

   //   infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    <% if current_user.address and current_user.lat %>
      var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= current_user.lat %>, <%= current_user.lng %>);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng});
      map.setCenter(currentlatlng);
      map.setZoom(11);
    <% end %>

  }

  $(function() {
      initialize_google_maps();
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodger/pbbhH/). What you need to do is to listen when Enter is pressed, take the first item from autocomplete container, geocode it and process the result.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({"address":firstResult }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
            placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
        $("input").val(firstResult);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mr.Pohoda, thanks for that, but couldn't get it working. I added your code to the bottom of my script. In console (Chrome) I get the error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewport' of undefined. Any other ideas? it's like the error isn;t in the code you provided, but when I take it out, I have no error in my already existing code.

Comment: If it works for you in the example above, there must be a problem with your code. Did you include Places library? Post your code to jsFiddle so we can take a look.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but my html and javascript is all linked up with ruby on rails stuff. not sure how to separate them...in any case, I've pasted what I think is the relevant code on jsfiddle...thanks for any help: http://jsfiddle.net/Christophe1/GpkYY/

Comment: Actually I've just added some code to the jsfiddle that I left out so you might want to refresh.

Comment: You are mixing html with templates and also javascript with templates which can't work (at least on jsFiddle). Maybe you have the same problem in your project - look at generated html and javascript and compare it with my example. If my answer works for you, consider mark it as a sollution.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I eventually used, which works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pac_input = document.getElementById('address_autocomplete');

  (function pacSelectFirst(input){
    // store the original event binding function
    var _addEventListener = (input.addEventListener) ? input.addEventListener : input.attachEvent;

    function addEventListenerWrapper(type, listener) {
      // Simulate a 'down arrow' keypress on hitting 'return' when no pac suggestion is selected,
      // and then trigger the original listener.
      if (type == "keydown") {
        var orig_listener = listener;
        listener = function (event) {
          var suggestion_selected = $(".pac-item.pac-selected").length > 0;
          if (event.which == 13 && !suggestion_selected) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var simulated_downarrow = $.Event("keydown", {keyCode:40, which:40})
            orig_listener.apply(input, [simulated_downarrow]);
          }

          orig_listener.apply(input, [event]);
        };
      }

      // add the modified listener
      _addEventListener.apply(input, [type, listener]);
    }

    if (input.addEventListener)
      input.addEventListener = addEventListenerWrapper;
    else if (input.attachEvent)
      input.attachEvent = addEventListenerWrapper;

  })(pac_input);

  function initialize_google_maps() {
    var midOfIreland = new google.maps.LatLng(53.252069, -7.860718);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: midOfIreland,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID
      streetViewControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var options = {
      types: ['geocode']
    };

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pac_input, options);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    // $(autocomplete).trigger("click");

    var contentstring = $('#info_window').html();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentstring, width:1, height:1});
    // for the 'x', to close the infoWindow, we give it the same behaviour as the 'No' link, in the infoWindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {   
      $(".map-no-link").trigger("click");
    });  

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(11);
      }

      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      $('#user_lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
      $('#user_lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      $('#changed').val('1');

      //infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    <% if current_user.address and current_user.lat %>
      var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= current_user.lat %>, <%= current_user.lng %>);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: currentlatlng});
      map.setCenter(currentlatlng);
      map.setZoom(11);
    <% end %>

  }

  $(function() {
      initialize_google_maps();
  });
</script>
```